# Import existing web application into Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've existing Web application developed and would like to import the entire repo into Bluemix. This web application required Web Server, Node.js and Bootstrap. Which is the most appropriate buildpack under CloundFoundry should I use?

I've uploaded my application to Github 
https://github.com/mikeytsk/signage_example_0408

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 3):

use following steps to add your git repository for Deploying app on Bluemix.

1) Create an app on bluemix by clicking on "Cloud Foundry app "and then
[image]

Then on Web -

[image]

and Then choose SDK for Node.js-

[image]

2) Give you App a name. You can see your App staging and started  on Bluemix.

[image]

3) Click on the App and you will be redirected to App overview page. There you will find ADD GIT option at top right corner.

[image]

4) A pop will appear asking you to create git Repository. Click on "Create" option to create one.

5) Now you can see a git repository created for you. The link is given at top right corner. But the Git repository created will be in hub.jazz.net not GITHUB. 
[image]

6) To Sync your app with Github account, click on the Git url, a new tab will open  with Git Repository shown to you. Click on the button at right top corner. 
[image]

7) A pop will come up. Select Change repository and link you Git hub account with Bluemix. 
[image]

8) Clicking on Authorise with Github will take you to github page, where you can authorise Bluemix to access your Repository. Once, its done. It will be easy for you to use your existing Repository with Bluemix.
In case, you can also go through the Bluemix Documentation for further clarity. Following is the link -
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/deploy_devops.html

Hope this helps you, Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Any idea how can I build and start rpc-server.js and web-server.js file as I couldn't get it running when i insert shell script from start.sh